# I have a tkinter table with Enter(), how can I convert it to Table()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
week = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

for course in self.courses:
    for i in range(course.start_time - 9, course.end_time - 9):
        self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='#181a1f',font=('Arial', 12))
        self.e.grid(row=i, column=Schedule.days.index(course.day))
        self.e.insert(END, course.name)
        week[Schedule.days.index(course.day)].remove(i)

for i in range(5):
    for hour in week[i]:
        self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='#181a1f', font=('Arial', 12))
        self.e.grid(row=hour, column=i)
        self.e.insert(END, "")
root = Tk()
schedule.print_table(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The code works fine, I've made a weekly schedule. But all cells are changeable I suppose thats because of `Entry()`. I tried using `state="readonly"` but then the cells disappeared.
And my second question is how can I add a empty first row and column, I want to write the days to the top of each column, and hours to left.

For that I tried adding 1 to row and column indexes, but weird things happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Label instead of Entry to make it readonly

To add empty rows/columns, you can create Labels/Entries with empty text and then increment the indices for the non-empty cells